# Full address geolocation UK

Tags: google-maps

I have been looking for a table of full UK addresses with longitude and latitudes.

I have already managed to find many sources of postcode to geolocation but i would like to get a more accurate location right up to the front door.

I know there are a couple of services out there that allow full address requests on webservices but i need to have this as a table as i will be doing 10000+ consecutive queries of it.

If anyone knows of anything i could use it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the addresses, you can use a geocoder. Here is an [example](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what i am looking for, i cant be making queries to googlemaps or any other web api as i need to process a large ammount of data.

Answer (score 0):

ideal-postcodes.co.uk has an address list service (https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/address-lists) which can provide you a UK address list including rooftop accurate geolocations for GB premises. It's possible to get a licence to do batch offline processing.

The bad news is it's not free. The data is sourced from commercial datasets from Royal Mail (PAF) and Ordnance Survey (AddressBase). The good news is, it's about two orders of magnitude cheaper compared to 2019, thanks to some OS license changes in 2020. A number of other Royal Mail data vendors should also start providing this in 2021, but I think Ideal Postcodes may be the first.

Disclaimer: I work for Ideal Postcodes